# How to replace only a word that starts with specific pattern

Tags: vim

I am trying to replace a word that has 3 characters in common, without replacing the whole sentence after matching the pattern.

Example:

```
He went to abcqwe a while ago.

He is in abc123 since morning.

He came from abcljkou yesterday night.
```

Now I want to replace words that start with `'abc'` with word `'New'`. This is the result I am expecting:

```
He went to new a while ago.

He is in abc123 since morning.

He came from new yesterday night.
```

I tried using:
`%s/abc.*/new/g`, but this one replaces the whole line after it matches the pattern.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what characters you want to count as a "word", but the following gives the expected result in your case:

```
:%s/abc[a-z]\+/new
```

This uses the [regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) "abc[a-z]+" (meaning the exact string "abc" followed by one or more lowercase letters) to match and replace words. You can add other ranges, like A-Z if you want to match uppercase letters as well.

Comment: Thank you I got the expected result now.

Answer (score 2):

Regular expressions are not magical.

The following regular expressions:

```
abc.*
```

matches:

- the string `abc` (`abc`),
- followed by zero or more (`*`) of any character except newline (`.`),

so it can't possibly be expected to solve the problem at hand.

What you actually want can probably (your question is not very precise) be expressed as "`abc` and the alphabetic characters that follow, as many as possible", which is written:

```
 abc\w\+
```

If you only want lowercase characters:

```
 abc\l\+
```

See `:help pattern-atoms`.

Answer (score 2):

To match a word that *starts with* a sequence of letters, you can prefix the `\<` atom. This will prevent "abc" in the middle of a word being replaced. Although such a case is not in the example you provide, it's better to be safe than sorry.

The rest of the regular expression works as per the excellent answers already provided by users [romainl](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77944170/796259) and [Noah Nazareth](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77943917/796259):

```
:%s/\<abc\l*/new/g
```

See [`:help /\<`](https://vimhelp.org/pattern.txt.html#%2F%5C%3C) for this atom, and [`:help /\l`](https://vimhelp.org/pattern.txt.html#%2F%5Cl) will take you directly to the explanation of the respective character class, showing that `\l` matches the same as `[a-z]` (only faster to type and faster to evaluate).

Answer (score 1):

Change the below vim substitute command

`:%s/\v<abc\w*>/new/gc`

`%` range substitution without any prompt at applying a file may have some unknown substitution.
Suggestion:

1. Add confirm flag before each substitution(`:h :s_flags`). Example:`:%s/apple/banana/gc`
2. Change `%` to `'<,'>`(select text at visual mode then press `:`), which means last you select text range. Example:`:'<,'>s/apple/banana/gc`